# Какк переназанчить this в DOM

Tags: javascript

есть `checkbox` и есть такой `script` :
-почему при `lastChecked = this` в консоли выдает последний и предпоследний отмеченный элемент?;
-почему при таком расположении в функции `handleCheck()` в консоли выдает последний и предпоследний отмеченный элемент, но если  `lastChecked = this` поставить перед `console.log` выдаст один и тот же, последний отмеченный элемент?;
-где можно больше узнать про переназначение `this` внутри функции, пытался найти, все ссылки `this` ведут на `this` в `object`?;

```
const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.item input[type="checkbox"]');

let lastChecked; 

function handleCheck() {

  console.log(this);
  console.log(lastChecked);
  lastChecked = this;
}

checkboxes.forEach(checkbox=> checkbox.addEventListener('click', handleCheck))
```

---

```
  <div class="inbox">
    <div class="item">
      <input type="checkbox">
      <p>item one</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <input type="checkbox">
      <p>item two</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <input type="checkbox">
      <p>item three</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> почему при lastChecked = this в консоли выдает последний и
>   предпоследний отмеченный элемент?;

this – это ссылка на объект элемента, если вы выделяете один и тот чекбокс, то this === lastChecked(одинаковые объекты), если разные – то они не будут равны.

> но если 
>   lastChecked = this поставить перед console.log выдаст один и тот же,
>   последний отмеченный элемент?;

Да, это присвоит в lastChecked  объект this, тогда вывод

```
console.log(this);
lastChecked = this;
console.log(lastChecked);
```

выведет одинаковые объекты.

> -где можно больше узнать про переназначение this внутри функции

Например, [тут ОЧЕНЬ хорошая статья](https://tproger.ru/translations/javascript-this-keyword/).

```js
const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.item input[type="checkbox"]');

let lastChecked; 

function handleCheck() {

  console.log(this);
  console.log(lastChecked);
  lastChecked = this;
}

checkboxes.forEach(checkbox=> checkbox.addEventListener('click', handleCheck))
```

```html
<div class="inbox">
  <div class="item">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <p>item one</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <p>item two</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <p>item three</p>
  </div>
</div>
```